# VMware player error on install vmware tools.

Tags: vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine, ubuntu-10.04

I've installed the last version of VMware player (4.0.2) and created a virtual machine with ubuntu 10.04. However, some operations with virtual machine cause errors which I'm confused about. For example, attempts to *Install VMware tools* fail with

*Could not find component on update server. Contact VMware support or your system administrator.*

error message.
Please help with an advice about how can I make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in vmware 4.0.2
I was also experiencing the same problem when i installed ubuntu 11.10
Please try to uninstall and install vmware player 4.0.1
That may solve the problem